# Customizing scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to learn parallax effect .I got this project from git hub
https://github.com/james-marshall/parallax.
But the only thing which irks me is the scroll bar .I am trying to put some customized scroll bar.
I am following this link  to achieve that 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/674478/Customize-Scrollbars-using-CSS3,but it does not fix my issue .I only get something like this.

[image]

How can I change that annoying scroll bar (top right),if not at least I can reset it to default (.i.e windows).I can not find any scroll bar settings (in css,I am a newcomer,I may have mistaken),and I dont know about java script.

How to do it ???

Here is the html part what i have tried

```
<body data-type="single" data-speed="32">

     <div class="scrollbar" id="ex3">
            <div class="content">Example 3</div>
     </div> 


  <div class="container">

    <div data-type="single" data-speed="8" id="divOne" class="div-one">
      <img src="img/up.png" alt="">
    </div> 


    <div data-type="single" data-speed="-16" id="divTwo" class="div-two"> 
      <img src="img/down.png" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

and this is the css part what i have added

```
.scrollbar{
width:150px;
height:300px;
background-color:lightgray;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:40px;
overflow-y:scroll;
float:left;
}
.content{
height:450px;
} 
#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar{
width:16px;
background-color:#cccccc;
} 
#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background-color:#B03C3F;
border-radius:10px;
}
#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#BF4649;
border:1px solid #333333;
}
#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
background-color:#A6393D;
border:1px solid #333333;
} 
#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
border:1px gray solid;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px gray inset;
}
```

Comment: Don't make the scrollbar CSS so precise to one element? http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: @Paulie_D any idea on how to reset to the default windows scroll bar look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you downloaded already uses [Nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll). If you want to disable it, just comment line 129 and 130 of script.js:

```
//var nice = $('html').niceScroll(); // The document page (body)
//$('#div1').html($('#div1').html() + ' ' + nice.version);
```

If you are using the minified version, you obviously need to rebuild and all that.

Answer (score 2):

try to use **[nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll)** which has some customization options. compatible with all major browsers.

Comment: can u help me in getting to reset it to default windows view.

Comment: please elaborate this "help me in getting to reset it to default windows view."

Comment: I mean to say that ,I wanted the default scroll bar view in the web Page.Anyway Problem got solved,it was because of the "nicescroll" when removed ,it came back to its default view.

Comment: oh. okay. glad to hear that your issue has been fixed. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

here is a small style :) add it anywhere in to your css file, u may edit is as you wish, hope it helps

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: what it does is the customized scroll bar comes up ,but when the page stops loading (loading completed),again that old scroll bar comes up
any guess on that on how to fix it ??

Comment: do you load any reset css? if you do make sure that you load it first